# Viewing comments to downvotes in Documentation Examples

Tags: support, downvote-reason, documentation

Today I downvoted [an example in Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/302/hello-world). A popup asked me to choose why and I commented on it

[image: downvote example]

But can anyone see this and if so where?
If not, this feature is not very useful.

Comment: Oh no, they did it! They actually implemented the "Force people to leave a comment when downvoting" feature request! A sick Meta joke they had great fun devising, I'm sure

Comment: I wasn't so sure about this Documentation thing, but was planning to withhold judgment until I saw it in action. Now I'm convinced it is a failure. Requiring a comment for a downvote? *Seriously?*

Comment: @CodyGray mmm, I don't know it's *that* bad yet. Documentation is likely going to see much lower participation rates than Q&A, that takes care of one main argument against requiring feedback to go with downvotes. And in general, critiquing a piece in documentation feels like a different beast than downvoting a question. We'll see... of course, getting a lot of "very low quality" downvotes needs to reliably shut you out from contributing to Documentation

Comment: The comment to a downvote  is no obligation.

Comment: I think asking for a bit of feedback probably isn't out of place seeing that one downvote in documentation seems to equal -10 rep for *everyone who ever edited that example.*

Comment: @nathan How do you know that? I have been completely unable to find any voting or reputation information of any kind for Documentation, even after the public release today. If what you say is true, I'll bet I just pissed a *bunch* of people off.

Comment: @pekka Obviously you wrote that comment before a giant blue banner appeared on the homepage prodding everyone to go contribute to Documentation. :-) Of course, I wrote my comment before I had access to it, so I didn't realize leaving a reason was optional. In fact, I didn't for some time after using it. The "x" looks like it would cancel my vote, too. You say critiquing documentation is different than downvoting a question; perhaps, but not different in my mind than downvoting an answer. There are lots of poor quality contributions I see there now, far worse than the typical answers I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downvote reasons become Improvement Requests:

[image: Improvement needed]

If you don't want to leave a public artifact, you can dismiss the prompt:

[image: No comment]

However, we hope that most people *will* leave feedback. Unlike questions and answers, which are usually the work of individuals, examples should be the result collaboration of several people. A downvote doesn't come with a reputation loss, so there will be no incentive for anyone to fix the problem unless the Improvement Request is created.

We don't have any plans to bring the dialog box (or anything like it) to Q&A. But a big new feature is as good a time to try new things as any. If it doesn't work, we can remove it without disrupting the habits of thousands of people. Since the path of least resistance is to pick one of the canned reasons<sup>*</sup> rather than making a custom comment, most of the reasons for not requiring comments on downvotes [I can think of](http://jericson.github.io/2015/05/18/downvotes.html) don't apply.

---

<sup>*</sup> Those reasons are *also* subject to change as we see how people use them. In particular, I'm worried the "very low quality" reason will [be misunderstood](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9942/15823).

Comment: Now you need that the X submits a vote with a "you are bad and we should make sure that you feel like that" by default when dismissing the dialog.

Comment: @Braiam: Huh? _Who_ should feel bad?

Comment: Did Microsoft help you design this bit of UI? Clicking the opt-out "x" looks suspiciously like it will cancel your entire attempt to vote. That's certainly what I thought it would do. I didn't find out different until I actually tried it, and even then I wasn't completely sure if it was a bug (perhaps an artifact of not forcing a page refresh?) until coming across your answer here. It is also surprising and not at all clear that my writing a custom flag reason will be turned into a *giant banner* with my comment in public view. Flags don't work this way, and this looks a lot like a flag.